# Is it possible to have extra (ignored) properties in C#?

Tags: c#, azure-cosmosdb, nosql

I have a repository for a `DocumentDb` database. My documents all have a set of common properties so all documents implement the IDocumentEntity interface.

```
public interface IDocumentEntity {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("documentClassification")]
    DocumentClassification DocumentClassification { get; set; }
}

public class KnownDocument : IDocumentEntity {
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    Guid Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("documentClassification")]
    DocumentClassification DocumentClassification { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("knownProperty")]
    string KnownProperty { get; set; }
}

public class BaseDocumentRepository<T> where T : IDocumentEntity {
    public Set(T entity) {
        // ... stuff
    }
}
```

This works fine with a `KnownDocument` where I know all of the properties. But, of course, what's great about a Document Db is that I don't need to know all of the properties (and in many cases I won't).

So my client submits something like this-

`{unknownProperty1: 1, unknownProperty2: 2}`

And I want to upsert this using my document repository.

```
public OtherDocumentService() {
_otherDocumentService = new OtherDocumentRepository();
}

public UpsertDocument(dynamic entity) {
    entity.id = new Guid();
    entity.documentClassification = DocumentClassification.Other;

    _otherDocumentRepository.Set(entity);
}
```

But I get an InvalidCastException from `dynamic` to `IDocumentEntity`. I assume it's because of the extra properties that exist on the dynamic object but not on the `IDocumentEntity` interface?

What I'm trying to do is leave my document entities open to be dynamic, but rely on a few properties being there to maintain them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity parameter passed to the UpsertDocument should explicitly implement IDocumentEntity  in order do make the code works, it is not enough just have a Id property.

Some options:

1) Proxy may be applied:

```
public class ProxyDocumentEntity : IDocumentEntity
{
        public dynamic Content { get; private set; }

        public ProxyDocumentEntity(dynamic @content)
        {
            Content = @content;
        }

        public Guid Id
        {
            get { return Content.Id; }
            set { Content.Id = value; }
        }
}
```

... using

```
public void UpsertDocument(dynamic entity)
{
            entity.Id = new Guid();         
            repo.Set(new ProxyDocumentEntity(entity));
}
```

The stored document will have nested Object property, which may be not acceptable

2)There is a lib https://github.com/ekonbenefits/impromptu-interface which creates a proxy dynamically
and does not make extra property like solution above. 
Drawback will be in performance.

Technically it could be 2 methods:

```
public void UpsertDocument(IDocumentEntity entity){...}
public void UpsertDocument(dynamic entity){...}
```

so the first (fast) will work for the objects which implement IDocumentEntity and second(slow) for the rest of the objects. 
But this is a speculation a bit , as I dunno the details of the whole code base of the project you have.

Comment: That's unfortunate but seems to be the way it has to go

Answer (score 0):

If you have some flexibility as to how to name those dynamic properties, you could stuff them into a Dictionary property on your object:

```
 public Dictionary<string, dynamic> extra { get; set; }
```